# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'startsWith'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Getting this error when trying to do message.channel.startsWith("xxx"), in python any reason why? I have discord 1.7.3 package installed

I tried installing different versions

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's the capital letter.

Try:

```
message.channel.startswith("xxx")
```

Comment: Also a tip:
if you want to explore what attributes an object has in Python, use `dir(object)`. In your case `dir(message.channel)`

Comment: Even better: read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)

Answer (score 0):

The attribute has a lower case w. Try using `message.channel.startswith("xxx")` instead

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a capital letter bro, try it:

message.channel.startswith("xxx")

i hope it's works :)

Answer (score 0):

2 Errors:

1. You have to use the **content** of the message, not the **channel**
2. You have to use the stats**w**ith with the 'w' lowercase

Use this:

```
if message.content.startswith("xxx"):
    # Do something
```